# mysql myisamchk vs mysqlcheck

Tags: mysql

We have a mysql database running version 5.0. Every month we shutdown the database for maintenance. We run a [`myisamchk`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk.html) on the tables to fix data fragmentation, and this takes down the system for up to an hour.

Will it be better to run [`optimize table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-table.html) daily via a cron so as to eliminate the downtime or is it necessary to do the [`myisamchk`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk.html) periodically ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the reference for [myisamchk](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-optimization.html) (emphasis mine):

> You can optimize a table *in the same way* by using the OPTIMIZE TABLE
>   SQL statement. OPTIMIZE TABLE does a table repair and a key analysis,
>   and also sorts the index tree so that key lookups are faster. There is
>   also no possibility of unwanted interaction between a utility and the
>   server, because the server does all the work when you use OPTIMIZE
>   TABLE.

I would run `optimize table` periodically (and as you suggested, more often than once as month so the operation completes faster) with the server running. Just [keep in mind](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-table.html):

> Note that MySQL locks the table during the time OPTIMIZE TABLE is running.

Answer (score 1):

I have a beautiful idea for you on this one...

If you can setup the following:

- Circular Replication

  - Two DB Servers
  - Each Server is a Master to the Other
  - Each Server is a Slave to the Other
- Use a DBVIP that will point to one DB Server
- Confine all Reads/Writes to the DBVIP

You can perform this `OPTIMIZE TABLE` maintenance on the DB Server that does not have the DBVIP.

First, construct the script on the Slave (the DB Server that does not have the DBVIP) that will run OPTIMIZE TABLE on all your tables. Then, run it on the Slave:

```
MYSQL_CONN="-u... -p..."
SQL="SELECT CONCAT('OPTIMIZE TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,';')"
SQL="${SQL} OptimizeTableSQL FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN"
SQL="${SQL} ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql')"
SQL="${SQL} ORDER BY (data_length+index_length)"
echo "SET sql_log_bin = 0;" > /root/OptimizeAllTables.sql
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -AN -e"${SQL}" >> /root/OptimizeAllTables.sql
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} < /root/OptimizeAllTables.sql
```

The first line of the script is `SET sql_log_bin = 0;`. This tells the session not to record `OPTIMIZE TABLE` in its binary logs. This prevents `OPTIMIZE TABLE` from running on the Master (the DB Server with the DBVIP). Once a month, you can just take down the DBVIP from one DB Server and bring up the DBVIP on the Other DB Server. When you do that, you must also setup the `OPTIMIZE TABLE` script to on the Other Machine. The key is to run this on the DB Server that does not have the DBVIP.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: +1 for an extremely convoluted by equally beautiful answer to the question. Should we retag `high availability`? ;)

Comment: Thanks for the solution I will not be able to do this for now but this is a good solution in the long term. As far as the DBVIP is concerned what tool would you suggest ? heartbeat/pacemaker perhaps ?

Comment: You can either heartbeat or pacemaker. My company uses ucarp ( www.ucarp.org or http://www.pureftpd.org/project/ucarp )